# Asp.net Web Api Streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to stream a file to my web service. In my Controller(ApiController) I have a Post function as follows:

```
public void Post(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        _websitesContext.Files.Add(new DbFile() { Filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), FileBytes= ToBytes(stream) });
        _websitesContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have been trying to stream a file with my web client by doing the following:

```
public void UploadFileStream(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    Stream postStream = myWebClient.OpenWrite(GetFileServiceUrl(), "POST");
    var buffer = ToBytes(file.InputStream);
    postStream.Write(buffer, 0,buffer.Length);
    postStream.Close();
}
```

Now when i debug my web service, it gets into the Post function, but stream is always null. Was wondering if anyone may have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: what is _websitesContext and how can you get a stream as the action parameter? probably you should access the request and response streams

Comment: _websitesContext is used to add entries into the database. Parv is it not possible to have a stream as an action parameter?

Comment: Also, as far as I know (but I might be mistaken, or remember wrongly here) this is not easily doable under ASP.NET, cause ASP.NET waits till the entirety of the request is uploaded till it calls whatever method/file lies at that end-point.

Answer (score 5):

Web API doesn't model bind to 'Stream' type hence you are seeing the behavior. You could instead capture the incoming request stream by doing: Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()

Example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Stream requestStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Note: you need not even have HttpRequestMessage as a parameter as you could always access this request message via the "Request" property available via ApiController.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace with this code

```
var uri = new Uri(GetFileServiceUrl());
Stream postStream = myWebClient.OpenWrite(uri.AbsoluteUri, "POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

[RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) makes this sort of stuff quite easy to do. Recommend trying it out.

Comment: RestSharp is a client REST library. He is writing a REST server. This does not answer his question.