# How can I tell Swashbuckle 5 that the body content is required in dotnetcore 3.0?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to implement Swashbuckle 5 and I have a couple of methods that read the Request Body like so:

```
var requestBody = await Request.GetRawBodyStringAsync();
```

How can I tell Swashbuckle/Swagger to read that as a parameter so that people can test out my API? I saw a very [similar question being asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141137/how-can-i-tell-swashbuckle-that-the-body-content-is-required) but that was for Binary content and for earlier versions of Swashbuckle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you already discovered in Swashbuckle 5 it is different because it switched to using the [Microsoft OpenApi.NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET). This is why the object model is different. Else it still works in the same way as the sample in the post you linked. I have translated the case to your scenario where you want to send a raw text string.

Create a custom Attribute to flag the methods that read raw strings. For example:

```
public class RawTextRequestAttribute : Attribute
{
   public RawTextRequestAttribute()
   {
      MediaType = "text/plain";
   }

   public string MediaType { get; set; }
}
```

To modify the Swagger definition you need a [Swashbuckle operation filter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#operation-filters) that will check for this attribute and if found customize the the request body to be a plain string. Here is a sample implementation to do that:

```
public class RawTextRequestOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
   public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
   {
      RawTextRequestAttribute rawTextRequestAttribute = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true)
         .SingleOrDefault((attribute) => attribute is RawTextRequestAttribute) as RawTextRequestAttribute;
      if (rawTextRequestAttribute != null)
      {
         operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody();
         operation.RequestBody.Content.Add(rawTextRequestAttribute.MediaType, new OpenApiMediaType() 
         {
            Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
            {
               Type = "string"
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

For the filter to be used you need to register it in the startup when you configure Swagger.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers();
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
      c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
      c.OperationFilter<RawTextRequestOperationFilter>();
   });
}
```

Then you add the attribute to the Methods where you read the raw request. For Example:

```
[HttpPost]
[RawTextRequest]
public async Task Post()
{
   var requestBody = await Request.GetRawBodyStringAsync();
   _logger.LogDebug(requestBody);
}
```

The result is that you get a text input box for the body of the request in Swagger UI.

[image: Swagger UI]

Comment: Were you able to get rid of the string keyword in the generated request body?

Comment: You mean the default value shown in the input box? There is a `Default` property on the `OpenApiSchema` object which I think specifies the value that is shown by default.

Comment: I tried the default property and it made no difference.

Comment: You can change it by using the `Example` property. It is the example value that is shown was wrong about the default. To have empty string value for example you set `Example = new OpenApiString("")`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!